# Automated data tracking during runtime in IDA PRO

Tags: ida

What I mean specifically is that I want to turn a certain piece of memory into a virus that will attach itself to anything that has anything to do with it. For example:

```
call sub_404505
; Lets say that sub_404505 returns a 32-bit integer in EAX register
; Here, I want to turn the EAX register into a virus
mov [esp + 0x?? + var_14], eax
mov some_global_offset, eax
; Here, I want this virus to extend to some_global_offset and var_14 stack address
; Later, if any read/write intructions has any reference to these addresses, I want IDA PRO to dump the intructions as well as the address of the intructions to output window
; This virus will remain in place until the value is reset, for example:
xor eax, eax
```

Is it possible to do something like this in IDA PRO, Windows 10?

Comment: Not to be impolite, but see at least three reasons why you will not receive an answer.  We're here to reverse engineer things, not make viruses.  IDA is not a virus making tool.  You're quoting 32bit code samples.  And – not to be impolite – your question is somewhat vapid and diaphanous, and your goals appear to be somewhat dubious.  Don't misunderstand me, I wrote a 32bit virus that attached itself to .com files when I was 16, which was around 1992, I didn't release it of course.  It was just about learning TSR techniques.

Comment: It sounds like you actually want a conditional breakpoint when a value gets modified, not a virus, although for a value in a register. Which I don’t think is easily possible, especially if you want to track the value through transfer between registers, moving on and off the stack, etc. I think you’ll have to do some of that analysis manually.

Comment: As mentioned by @Rup, what I meant by virus here is mostly in reference to its 'contagious' property, I'm not really trying to do anything malicious. I was hoping that there'd be some way to automate the process mentioned by Rup either via native IDA PRO tools or even some idapython scripting.